# Allow only determinated providers and extensions

Tags: regex

I want allow only email hosts `@protonmail.ch`, `@outlook.AnyExtension`, `@hotmail.AnyExtension` and `@yahoo.AnyExtension`. I tried this regex, but it didn't work:

```
\b[\w\.-]+@((?!prontomail|outlook|hotmail|yahoo).)[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b
```

Can someone please give me some hints?

Comment: Think easier: `.+@(prontomail\.ch|outlook\.\w+|hotmail\.\w+|yahoo\.\w+)`

Comment: Welcome! I've edited your question a bit, so it's a bit easier to read. On StackOverflow, we always appreciate some more text including the actual question and some more information. (e.g. why didn't this work correctly for you? in what cases does it fail? etc.)

Comment: @WouterJ Ok, thanks for the tips and correction.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
/@protonmail\.ch|@(outlook|hotmail|yahoo)\.\w{2,}$/
```

- `...$` means: match `...` at the end of the string
- `\w{2,}` means: match any word character 2 or more times (`+` means 1 or more btw)
- `a|b` means: match a or b
- `(a|b)...` means: match a... or b...